# Excel: SUMing values that fall in a range (Extending SUMIFS to use ranges of Criteria)

Tags: sum, excel-formula

First post - please be gentle.

I have an interesting problem where I'm trying to convert a flat data table into a cumulative total based on two ranges (to create cumulative graphs of progress).  Something that should be really easy to do.

I've managed to collate the data into a summary table (effectively a pivot table but for layout and charting purposes I cant use an actual pivot table).

(I'm too new to post images - sorry its not embedded)

[Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13145623/Excel.png)

In this screenshot I'm trying to show the 3 columns on the left as a Flat data table.
    Columns A & B are text values that can be 'any' text (so I cant use wild cards).
    Column C is the value I'd like to SUM.

Currently I'm using an SUMIFS statement to find the sum of the "Hours" when the "Week" label matches the values in "column A" and the "Department" label matches the value in "Column B".

**I would like to change this equation to find the cumulative value for each week (so in this example cell G6 would be 14 - i.e. 4 from week 1 and 10 from week 2.)**

I would like to try and avoid duplicating the entire table just to find the cumulative
All I really need to be able to do in this example is replace the equation in F5:

```
    =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$15,$B$2:$B$15,$E5,$A$2:$A$15,F$4)
```

with

```
    =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$15,$B$2:$B$15,$E5,$A$2:$A$15,$F$4:F$4)
```

eg Sum the hours of all the weeks that have come before.  Again - i cant use wild cards and I cant use pivot tables.

I imagine I need to use some Array formulae but I cant find any online resources to help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Further to this I've found that  the SUMPRODUCT works quite well in this scenario:

        =SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$15=$F$4:F$4)*($B$2:$B$15=$E5)*($C$2:$C$15))

However you need to know the number of rows otherwise it returns #value. - As i don't know this I don't think i can use this function?

Comment: you could make the range dynamic, mit offset and index. Be only aware that with sumproduct is important to exclude the first row (sumproduct is picky and sum only numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Your formula works in Cell F5, but in G5 just make it add F5.

```
F5 =SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,$E5,$A:$A,F$4)
G5 =SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,$E5,$A:$A,G$4)+F5
H5 =SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,$E5,$A:$A,H$4)+G5
I5 =SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,$E5,$A:$A,I$4)+H5
```

Also use the entire column reference A:A if you dont know the total number of rows.
If you cant do that you could make your read data into a table and then instead of the sum_range being some defined locations, you can use Table1[Week] = Column A instead.

Hope this helps

-Scheballs